# CUDA get desire compute data

Tags: cuda, parallel-processing

I am learning and I am confused by threadIdx.x, blockIdx.x
if I have a data which's size is 5x5 , and I want to use column as an input for individual computation

```
   1 2 3 4 5              1    2    3    4    5
   2 3 4 5 6              2    3    4    5    6
   3 4 5 6 7        ->    3    4    5    6    7         
   4 5 6 7 8              4    5    6    7    8
   5 6 7 8 9              5    6    7    8    9 

 original data         5 input data do same kernel computation
```

how should I use the cuda threadIdx.x and blockIdx.x corresponding to kernel`<<<par1,par2>>>`
to deal this kind of problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach with 2D data is to launch a 2D threadblock/grid:

```
#define DHEIGHT 256
#define DWIDTH 256
...
dim3 threads(16,16);
dim3 blocks((DWIDTH/threads.x)+1, (DHEIGHT/threads.y)+1);
kernel<<<blocks, threads>>>(...);
```

and in your kernel definition, you would use two variables (let's say `row` and `col`) to identify the thread and which element to work on for that thread:

```
int row = threadIdx.y+blockIdx.y*blockDim.y;
int col = threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

if ((row < DHEIGHT) && (col < DWIDTH)){

  // process element at (row, col)
}
```

It's also possible to handle this using a 1D grid/threadblock structure, and then the indexing calculation for `row` and `col` just becomes a little different/more complicated.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but why the blocks need +1 in each dimension?

Comment: The calculation is using integer division to compute the number of threadblocks (in x and y directions).  The +1 is a quick way to make sure we launch enough threadblocks so that even partial threadblocks are covered.  For example, suppose your DHEIGHT was 257 instead of 256.  Without the +1, the integer division would yield 257/16 = 16, and we wouldn't have enough threadblocks.  When we make these adjustments, we need the "thread check" in the kernel that tests for threads outside the valid region `if ((row < DHEIGHT) && (col < DWIDTH)){`